# Count web visits in laravel/ php

Tags: php, laravel

I have a news website, and I want to show my web visits on my web's homepage. This web is created by laravel framework. 
I just want to show only web visits. So I wish you show me an easy way.I tried to find this in google, but I didn't find the best answer I want. Hope you help me. Thanks all!

Comment: How do you define a "web visit"?

Comment: Oh, maybe a session when someone visit my web

Comment: Are you hosting this on Geocities? I'm sure if you search on Google you will find tons of tutorials from about 10 years ago explaining how to do this.

Comment: Make IP/browser/language... hash and store that... I am sure packages already exist to make this easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create middleware and apply it to all routes excluding Ajax and other ones which you do not want to count. Then just use `DB::insert()` to store every visit information in some table, it's simpliest and fast enough solution.

To make sure it will store data just once per session, you can use `session()` to store boolean:

```
session(['visit-saved' => true]);
```

And then check it every time in same middleware:

```
if (!session('visit-saved')) {
    DB::table('visits')->insert([....]);
}
```

Comment: You would have to make sure it only runs once per session though.

Comment: Well depends on what you want to count. Page views or sessions